# How to use a C# Enum in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C# assembly containing an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    OK = 0, 
    NOT_OK = -1
}
```

I've added the reference to the `C++/CLI` project but I don't know how to return a value from a function.

Header:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace MyNamespace;

namespace NativeWrapper {

    public ref class API
    {
        public:
            static MyNamespace::MyEnum Go();
    };

}
```

CPP:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "API.h"

using namespace NativeWrapper;

MyNamespace::MyEnum API::Go()
{
    return MyEnum.OK;
}
```

I get the following when I build the project:

`error C2275: 'MyNamespace::MyEnum' : illegal use of this type as an expression`

Comment: Nitpick: It's "native", not "unmanaged". (You don't see native developers calling the CLR "unnative", do ya? :P )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need colons, not a period.

```
MyNamespace::MyEnum API::Go()
{
    return MyEnum::OK;
}
```

Also, note that if MyEnum was originally written in C++/CLI, you'd need to declare it as `public enum class MyEnum { ... }` to make it a managed enum that you can use from C#.